# How to capture/get the step level information in selenium

Tags: selenium

As per my knowledge,TestNG listener works only at method level and capture the test execution information up to method level. I have created my own customized listener and tried to get the step execution information but i failed. I want to get the Method'Step level execution information in selenium.I have also tried with creating my own annotation but not get success.

Actually, I want to get the Method'Step level execution information in selenium. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use log4j to capture logs for each step. Visit [here](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-create-log-files-in-selenium/) for more info